# How to add bullet point lines in CSS?

Tags: css

I am using obsidian app for note taking.I want add bullet point lines like remnote/roam research to obsidan app. I tried the method shown in the video but it didn't work.If anyone can help I'll highly appreciate that. thanks in advance.

https://youtu.be/rukFr8CjzPo

[Does anybody skillful in CSS know how to archive those navigation lines?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBQvv.png)

I tried adding this code as a snippet but it didn't work.

```
/* BULLET POINT RELATIONSHIP LINES */

.cm-hmd-list-indent .cm-tab, ul ul, ol ol { 
  position: relative; 
}

.cm-hmd-list-indent .cm-tab::before, ul ul::before, ol ol::before {
  content: '';
  border-left: 1px solid #EEE;
  position: absolute;
}

.cm-hmd-list-indent .cm-tab::before { 
  left: 0; 
  top: -5px; 
  bottom: -4px; 
}

ul ul::before, ol ol::before { 
  left: -11px; 
  top: 0; 
  bottom: 0;
}
```

here is my current output so far, which is not correctly display perfectly as expected

[image]

Comment: Hi ! Please post **here** at least a screenshot of what you need, plus the attempts you've made with css, as it is your only tag. Thanks !

Comment: Would https://forum.obsidian.md/t/how-do-i-create-a-bulleted-list/5449 help you out?

Comment: Thanks for your css part Jenny ! What about frontend html code to work with ? :)

Comment: We'll have to see your HTML to make sense of what your CSS is supposed to do. (This is probably why the snippet feature didn't work - without HTML, there's nothing for the CSS to apply to.)

Comment: did u watch the video. there's nothing to do with html part. this is an software called obsidian. It is a small software around 200mb. you can download it and see all the css part there.

Comment: No I didn't and won't. But your question is certainly relevant [here](https://forum.obsidian.md/) :)

Comment: Lol. I already posted that question there.

Comment: "there's nothing to do with html part" – not everyone answering here will be using Obsidian. If you want everyone to be able to answer, adding some representative HTML will let them! Otherwise, this is just an Obsidian support question :)